# Deligne’s letter to Kazhdan on $\ell$-adic Fourier transform

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I wonder if anyone has a copy of Deligne's letter to Kazhdan, dated 29 November 1976. The letter is on the $\ell$-adic Fourier transform. In his essay on Deligne's work on the occasion of the Abel prize, Illusie cites Laumon's paper and his own article in Algebraic Geometry - Bowdoin 1985 as auxiliary references, but I am curious to read the 1976 letter. (It is not listed on Deligne's IAS page or Wikipedia article.) Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to Beilinson & Drinfeld I was able to make a copy of this letter, now online at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ufc66njc36svfm1/deligne_to_kazhdan.pdf.